# How can I specify what arguments are valid in a function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, parameters, arguments

I have a function:

`ShowMessage(message As String, type As String)`

There are only three valid inputs for `type` - "Error", "Warning", and "Success". I want to make it so that as you're typing in the function and you get to the `type` parameter, a drop down appears with the valid inputs.

Is this even possible? If I can't do it with strings, can I build an array of options or something?

Comment: You want an Enum: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixing a few things:

```
Friend Enum MessageType
  Success
  Warning 
  Critical             ' Error is reserved, use [Error] or something else
End Enum

 Sub ShowMessage(message As String, mType As MessageType)
```

To use it as you might have been when it was a string, say as a Msgbox Title:

```
Dim msgType as String = mType.ToString
```

This converts `MessageType.Critical` into `"Critical"` and is why I did not use [Error] above - to avoid brackets in the text.

`.ToString` only works when the variable is declared as MessageType,  If `mtype` is actually an integer which happens to acquire a MessageType value, .ToString will return "2".  In that case, cast the integer to get the Enum Name:

```
Dim msgType as String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(mType))
'or
msgType = [Enum].Parse(GetType(MessageType), mType).ToString
```

Comment: Ahh I fixed his right as you posted yours with all the corrections! What's the reason for using 'Friend'? Also why not just .ToString?

Comment: Not getting "2", I'm getting "Critical". Anyway it's all working, and you got it right off the bat, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You should use an enum when there's a limited, pre-defined number of options to choose from

```
Enum MessageType
    [Error],
    Warning,
    Success
End Enum
```

(Error has to be in square brackets as it's a keyword)

and your call would be

```
 ShowMessage(message As String, type As MessageType)
```

Comment: I can't edit at the moment as there is a pending edit but Error should be in square brackets: `[Error]` as it's a keyword. I'll update it as soon as I can.